# How can I get a proper dark mode working for Kate?

Tags: themes, colors, appearance, kate

I can't seem to be able to get a proper
[dark mode working for Kate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U82t1.png).

The system is in dark mode, as configured in Settings -> Appearance -> Style.

In Kate, the default color scheme is Breeze Dark, the editor part itself is in dark mode but not the rest.

Installing breeze and reopening Kate yielded no different results.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y breeze
```

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Kate version 21.12.3

EDIT: After a system update the issue has seem to resolved itself, changing the color scheme now changes all the colors. I suppose if someone has a "proper fix" they can chime in.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1240018/how-to-change-the-colour-of-kate-text-editors-ui

Comment: That is literally what I have already tried, but to no avail. System is in dark mode, default scheme is Breeze Dark, only the editor changes color but not the toolbars and such, as shown in the picture in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A little update on this. So, I went through this on another machine. This was actually Linux Mint 21 but I hope it will work also for Ubuntu.
Install following

```
sudo apt install breeze plasma-desktop systemsettings
```

Run

```
systemsettings
```

and change to dark theme in the "Quick Settings" page.